# How can i make a bash script run whenever a different program is run?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, alias

I have a bash script that I need to start whenever a command (in this case, "adduser") is run.

what I came up with so far is this

```
alias adduser="bash PATH/script.sh; adduser"
```

obviously this is not the best way, i was wondering if there is some other way to do it.

Comment: Make a script with the same name and make sure it comes first in the `PATH`, then use the absolute path for the real executable?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a function

```
adduser () {
    bash PATH/script.sh
    command adduser "$@"
}
```

but the alias isn't terrible.